# Dominant Colors in multiple images

Tags: python, image-processing, histogram, k-means, opencv

I am trying to find an algorithm to find the average dominant colors of multiple images with python. I've found an algorithm that extracts the dominant colors of a single image with a KMeans Cluster. The Cluster is then fed into an histogram function and is finally plotted with the matplot library.

I'm fairly new to python and coding in general and I couldn't find a way to either **merge multiple cluster data into one** or **merge multiple histograms** What would be the smartest solution?

What I'm trying to find in an example. Say You have two images, the first one ist 50% cyan and 50% yellow and the second one is 50% cyan and 50% red – I would like to have a combined and weighted output like:  50% cyan 25% red and 25% yellow.

**This is my code so far**

```py
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


def find_histogram(clt):
    """
    create a histogram with k clusters
    :param: clt
    :return:hist
    """
    numLabels = np.arange(0, len(np.unique(clt.labels_)) + 1)
    (hist, _) = np.histogram(clt.labels_, bins=numLabels)

    hist = hist.astype("float")
    hist /= hist.sum()

    return hist


def plot_colors2(hist, centroids):
    bar = np.zeros((50, 300, 3), dtype="uint8")
    startX = 0

    for (percent, color) in zip(hist, centroids):
        # plot the relative percentage of each cluster
        endX = startX + (percent * 300)
        cv2.rectangle(bar, (int(startX), 0), (int(endX), 180), color.astype("uint8").tolist(), -1)
        startX = endX

    return bar

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("pics/*.jpg")]


for image in images:
    imageRGB = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    imageReshape = imageRGB.reshape((imageRGB.shape[0] * 
    imageRGB.shape[1],3)) #represent as row*column,channel number

    cluster = KMeans(n_clusters=3) #cluster number
    cluster.fit(imageReshape)

    print(cluster)

    histogram = find_histogram(cluster)
    #print("histogram", histogram)

    bar = plot_colors2(histogram, cluster.cluster_centers_)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.imshow(bar)
    plt.show()
```